# Get-ACL Set-ACL removes inherited groups

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I'm trying to set folder rights for a group like this:

\server\Share$\Folder1\Folder2

Traverse on Share$ -> Traverse Folder1 -> Modify Folder2

There are more folders in the share but the group should not gain any access. That's why I set "None","None" for the Inheritance & Propagation flags in $AccessRuleTraverse .

```
$AccessRuleModify = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("TestGroup","Modify","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$AccessRuleTraverse = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("TestGroup","Traverse,ListDirectory","None","None","Allow")


$ACL = Get-Acl $Share
$ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRuleTraverse)
$ACL | Format-List
Set-Acl -Path $Share $ACL

$ACLFolder1 = Get-Acl $Folder1
$ACLFolder1.AddAccessRule($AccessRuleTraverse)
$ACL | Format-List
Set-Acl -Path $Folder1 $ACLFolder1

$ACLFolder2 = Get-Acl $Folder2
$ACLFolder2.AddAccessRule($AccessRuleModify)
$ACL | Format-List
Set-Acl -Path $Folder2 $ACLFolder2
```

When I do this via the UNC path the TestGroup is added but all inherited groups are removed: BUILTIN\Administrators,SYSTEM and another AD group that is inherited from the level above. If I check in the GUI inheritance seems enabled and when I disable & re-enable it the mysteriously missing groups are back.

If I add '$ACL | Format-List' before Set-ACL it returns the groups...

Get-Acl shows:

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\server\tbd$\test2
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : DOMAIN\Domain Users
Access :
         DOMAIN\admaccount Allow  FullControl
         DOMAIN\InheritedGroup Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:DUD:AI(A;OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-2288239599-1684634387-2072)(A;OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-2288239599-1684634387-55095)(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIID;FA;;;BA)
```

After the .AddAccessRule:

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\server\tbd$\test2
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : DOMAIN\Domain Users
Access :
         DOMAIN\TestGroup Allow  ReadData, ExecuteFile, Synchronize
         DOMAIN\admaccount Allow  FullControl
         DOMAIN\InheritedGroup Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:DUD:AI(A;;0x100021;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-2288239599-1684634387-61957)(A;OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-2288239599-1684634387-2072)(A;OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-2288239599-1684634387-55095)(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIID;FA;;;BA)
```

EDIT:

After feedback I tested directly on the server with a local path:

```
$AccessRuleTraverse = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("TestGroup","Traverse,ListDirectory","None","None","Allow")
$ACL = Get-Acl F:\tbd\test2
$ACL | Format-List
$ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRuleTraverse)
$ACL | Format-List
Set-Acl -Path F:\tbd\test2 $ACL
```

Get-Acl shows:

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::F:\tbd\test2
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : BELGIANRAIL\Domain Users
Access : BELGIANRAIL\admaccount Allow  FullControl
         BELGIANRAIL\InheritedGroup Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
Audit  : 
Sddl   : O:BAG:DUD:AI(A;OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-2288239599-1684634387-2072)(A;OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-2288239599-1684634387-55095)(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIID;FA;;;BA)
```

After the  .AddAccessRule:

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::F:\tbd\test2
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : BELGIANRAIL\Domain Users
Access : BELGIANRAIL\TestGroup Allow  ReadData, ExecuteFile, Synchronize
         BELGIANRAIL\admaccount Allow  FullControl
         BELGIANRAIL\InheritedGroup Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
Audit  : 
Sddl   : O:BAG:DUD:AI(A;;0x100021;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-2288239599-1684634387-61957)(A;OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-2288239599-1684634387-2072)(A;OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3230232255-228823959
         9-1684634387-55095)(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIID;FA;;;BA)
```

It looks the same as through the UNC path. But the end result is totally different, with the local path it works fine! I guess I could get the local path and start a remote ps session.. It would be easier with the UNC path though :)

Comment: I've seen this problem years ago when using Explorer GUI or `ICACLS.EXE` to modify ACLS against a UNC path. Does the problem also occur if you run Set-ACL locally with against the local (non-UNC) path?

Comment: @Craig620 you're right, with a local path it works. I've updated the question.